# iPad Enterprise app -> popup 'XXX would like to install YYY' does not appear

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, enterprise-distribution

I have uploaded an IPA file (Enterprise distribution) to diawi.com, and can download it on my own iPad no problem.

1. Visit diawi.com/xyzxyz
2. Click Install Application
3. A popup appears, asking "XXX would like to install YYY". Click Install
4. App appears on Home screen

I sent the link to a client, but when he follows this procedure, he does not get a popup in step 3. What could be a possible cause?

I also tried the same procedure using installfish.com instead of diawi.com, but also there I can install the app without a problem, but my client does not get the proper popup.

Additional information:

- The app is packaged using Xcode 7
- Both me and my client are using iOS 9.2

Comment: what was the cause & solution

Comment: I still don't know. We managed to get the app on his iPad directly, but never found the issue.

Comment: Thank You for reply. Hopefully the below solution may work

Comment: I find a similar question here, but that solution is quite hard to execute for our customers. http://support.hockeyapp.net/discussions/problems/51764-ios-9-does-not-show-install-dialog-after-tapping-install-button

Answer (score 0):

Ensure Java Script is enabled for safari by moving into iPad settings -> Safari -> Advanced

Comment: I have the issue again now. Unfortunately, this is not the solution. If I disable this setting, I cannot reproduce the issue. If the customer enables this setting, he still cannot download the build.

Comment: Can you try this in different browser apart from safari?